# Socket.io not emitting to Angular js client from Node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io

My intention is to get a client to broadcast the status of a song being played at different stages of the song progress.

This is my client side code

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope, $http) {


 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

 socket.on('connect',function(){
 socket.emit('message', 'Hello server');
   });



 socket.on('songStartFromServer', function(data) {
 console.log('Song Started From Server' + data.soundUrl);

 })

  socket.on('broadcastPosition', function(data){

  console.log('new position !!!!');

   });

   socket.on('sampleEmit', function(data){

   console.log('Sample Emit ' + data.sampledata);
   });    


soundManager.setup({

// where to find the SWF files, if needed
url: '/path/to/swf-directory/',

onready: function() {
  // SM2 has loaded, API ready to use e.g., createSound() etc.

var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
    url: 'path to url',

  whileplaying: function() {
  $(".progBar").css('width', Math.ceil((this.position/this.duration) * 100) + '%');

    var currentPercentage = (this.position / this.duration) * 100;
    console.log( currentPercentage + '%');

    if ((currentPercentage > 5) && (currentPercentage < 5.1)) {

      socket.emit('broadcastSongProgress', {position: this.position});
     // mySound.setPosition('mySound', 1000);

      };
},

});

    $scope.emitData = function() {
      mySound.play();
      socket.emit('songStart', {soundUrl: mySound.url});     
      };
},
 ontimeout: function() {

}
});
```

Heres my Server side code, the idea is to emit 'broadcastPosition' when 'broadcastSongProgress' comes in to server

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

socket.emit('sampleEmit', {sampledata: 'mysample'});


socket.on('soundManagerReady', function(data){

console.log('emit received from client!');

});

socket.on('broadcastSongProgress', function(data){
socket.emit('broadcastPosition', data);
console.log('SONG IS AT ' + data.position);


});
socket.on('songStart', function(data){

console.log('SONG STARTED AND URL IS ' + data.soundUrl);

socket.emit('songStartFromServer', data);
});

});
```

// client receiving

```
socket.on('broadcastPosition', function(data){

//this is not logging on client side even though it gets to the server
console.log('new position!!' + data.position);

});
```

Comment: You probably need to add more code here. It's hard to tell how the receiving code relates to the rest of the application. Also the `io.connect()` call that initiates the connection appears to be missing.

Comment: @AnthonyChu , I have updated the code with what I omitted, the io.connect was in my code. Thanks for your anticipated response.

Comment: @AnthonyChu figured out the issue, I need to send io.sockets.emit('broadcastPosition', data); instead of sockets.emit....